# How to view Nifi registry changes / commit history for each version

Tags: apache-nifi

Is it possible to view the changes made to a process group for each version stored in a Nifi registry?

Right-clicking on a versioned process group in Nifi only gives you the option to `change version` or `stop version control`, and the `Change Version` dialog window does not give commit information aside from the version, date and comment.

I would like to be able to view each change after a new version has been committed, much like it appears in the `Show local changes` list before the version is committed. Is this possible?

Answer (score 3):

Currently there isn't a good way to do this from the NiFi side, but it is definitely something we should support in the future.

There is a REST end-point in registry that may give you what you are interested in...

GET
/buckets/{bucketId}/flows/{flowId}/diff/{versionA}/{versionB}

https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-registry-docs/rest-api/index.html

Comment: Sorry, I haven't had time to test this yet, I will get back to you as soon as I have (and accept your answer)! The REST end-point is a perfect solution for me, thanks.

Comment: Any updates on this? Is there a better solution offered in that regard?